# "Apply modifiers" button not appearing?

Tags: interface, modifiers

I am attempting to follow a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttU6Gz1W0Xw) for decimating a model - I need to do this for a continuous LOD in a game I am creating.

However, in the tutorial, he uses some "Apply modifiers" button, which I can't find anywhere!

If I start up blender with the default box, I see it, but when I open a .blend, or import a model, the button disappears!

Screenshot:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The button should be on the modifier itself.. Does selecting the object in object mode, then pressing Alt C > *convert to mesh* work?

Comment: @gamdalf3 I pressed ALT+C, but there is no "Convert to mesh" option.

I am using blender 2.7

Comment: It should be part of the modifier http://i.stack.imgur.com/6NfsK.png You need to be in object mode to apply it.

Comment: @cegaton On that screenshot, you see that little button of a spanner? I can't see that after I import or open a model.

Comment: Could you add a screen grab on your question?

Comment: @cegaton My apologies - Should have done that from the start.

Comment: You need an *active object* in order to do thing like apply modifiers. Click on an object with RMB to make it active (it should appear with a yellow outline).

Comment: @gandalf3 Heh, that fixed it. Such a stupid mistake. I am just such a blender newbie :(.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The apply modifier button will be on the modifier.

#### Blender 2.9x

In Blender 2.9x click on the top triangle to apply the modifier, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

[image]

See: [How to apply a modifier in V2.9+](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/193185/31447)

#### Blender 2.7x

[image: apply modifier button]

You have to be in object mode to apply modifiers. Applying the  modifier does not work on multiple selections, only the active object gets applied.

Comment: THANK YOU. The fact that you need to be Object Mode, *not* Edit mode, to apply a modifier (which is an Edit) is bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the object you want to edit is [*active*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/selecting.html#selections-and-the-active-object) (yellow outline). Usually the active object is always the last selected object, however sometimes you can end up without an active object after doing things such as importing.

To make an object the active object, click on it with <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> (use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> if you want to preserve the existing selection).