# Adding an image to a mirrored object

Tags: image

When I'm trying to add an image to my mirrored object I can only do it on the non mirrored side, is it possible to add the image to the whole thing?

Comment: Could you post a .blend file using a service like http://pasteall.org/blend/, or at least some screen shots, its hard to know *exactly* what you've done.

Comment: have you applied the modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [UV Project Modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Modify/UV_Project), to project a texture on to your mirrored model.

If you are using the UV map (without the Project Modifier) then no there is no way. You will have to [apply](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17737/2217) the mirror modifier.
With a mirror modifier on a model, there is only half the mesh, and thus half the UVs to texture with. So anything that is one the first half, will be mirrored to the other half, including materials and textures.

Comment: Notice that UV's are mirrored to the other half.

Comment: What about Generated mapping. UVs are not an only option how to texture object, blended box mapping is powerfull too..