# How can I subdivide this plane into even squares?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have a plane that has a scale of `x: 100, y: 5, z: 1`, and I want to split it into squares that have a scale of `x: 5, z: 5`, but when I do subdivide, I get a result like this:

[image: Unwanted subdivision]

When in reality, I'd rather have something like this:

[image: Wanted subdivision]

How can I do this? *(Sorry for the badly sketched pictures.)*

Comment: You could also subdivide the individual *edges* and then manually connect them into faces. However, loop cuts are much better in a simplistic situation such as this.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Why not just add a grid instead of a plane?  It's right next to Monkey in 2.80.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use loop cuts, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and use the scroll wheel to select how many. Hover over the edge you want the cuts to intersect, then double-click to finish the action.

[image]

Comment: @Ethan Bierlein Note that you will need to create 20 loops for perfect squares if the dimensions you listed are still true.

Comment: As far as I can see, the loop cut is applied to the ONE face. What if I have multiple faces selected and want it to be applied to EACH of the selected faces in the same way?

Answer (score 11):

1. Add a plane (in object mode) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Plane*.
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> in to edit mode, and scale the plane up by 5, <kbd>S</kbd> `5`.
3. Add an array modifier, all setting at default except *Count*, change the *Count* to be `20`.
4. [Apply](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17737/2217) the modifier, must be in object mode to apply modifiers.
5. <kbd>Tab</kbd> back in to edit mode, and remove doubles with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or *Tool Shelf* > *Tools* tab > *Remove Doubles*

Now you have a perfectly sized plane evenly split in to 10 unit squares.

Answer (score 8):

You can actually do it this way:

1. Select the two edges you want to cut between.
2. Click the subdivide button once. A menu appears that looks like:
   [image: Subdivide options]
3. Increase the *Number of Cuts* amount.