# trying to make a patio with support beams

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was trying to make a patio with support beams, I started with a cube for the house. I extruded the front bottom edge to become the patio surface. Then I wanted to create evenly spaced squares along the front edge to become the beams. Is there a better way to do this? I wanted to create a 4x4 square at the vertex of the patio, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, grab, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> repeat it across the patio

Comment: Please include images of what you have tried/would like.

Comment: [How can I subdivide this plane into even squares?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23821/2217) may be of help to you.

Comment: If you're using the vertices from the edge of the patio. Once duplicated & extruded to desired height. Press "Control + P" then add a solidify modifier to the new object.

Comment: I'll try this, I saw a tutorial where they converted vertices to a shape, but I couldn't figure out how they did it.