# Saving a mesh from a frame in a cloth simulation?

Tags: animation, mesh, cloth-simulation

So right now I'm trying to put a mesh of a small pouch on the side of one of my characters. While I could make it like I would any other mesh, it would look kind of un-natural. When playing around in blender though, I noticed if you were to use the cloth effect to drape it over a few object that are close together, it makes something much like the desired effect.

So my question is, could I take the 'animated' cloth dropping over an object, say at frame 60, and make that the default way the shape is? Of course allowing me to then rotate it upward and edit it to the character.

Comment: you can apply a cloth modifer at any frame

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can. You have to [apply](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17737/2217) the cloth simulation.

Go to the frame where your object is looking the way you want it to (frame 60).
In the *Properties* panel under the *Modifiers* tab click the large *Apply* button on the cloth modifier. That will get rid of all the cloth simulation settings, and make the mesh "real", (just like applying any other modifier.)
[image: modifiers tab of the properties panel]