# Sculpted with Multiresolution, enable Dynamic Topology wrecks mesh

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

[image: multiresolution sculpted mesh]

That's my sculpted head, the base mesh is very simple. I have done this with normal sculpting and multiresolution modifier.
Now when I enable Dynamic Topology it throws my sculpting in the trash and I get the base mesh.
Toggling the dynamic Topology off, I get such a sculpt:
[image: after dynamic topology]

How can I rescue my sculpting work and still use dynamic topology?
Should I retopology the mesh?
The mesh will be 3d printed, is it enough to apply the multiresolution modifier in the end, to get the sculpting into the print?

Comment: your aware that the supports on that guys neck will be huge?

Comment: What do you mean with the support on the neck O.o?

Comment: when you print with an additive printer it needs to  make supports that the plastic falls onto far any overhang of 45 degrees or more.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I didn't know... Do I have to model the support too or does this the printer on itself?

Comment: most printers do it by themselves, but I'm just letting you know because they can be a pain to remove.

Comment: @VinceScalia not necessarily, if it is printed laying down (with the chin up) then there will be many fewer supports.

Comment: the jawbone and pats of the side of the head might get those really annoying ones that stick so close to the model you can't get them off. :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Multiresulition modifier simply does not work with dynamic topology.

When you try to enable dynamic topology with a Multiresulition modifier on the mesh you will get a warning message like this:

> Warning!
>   Generative Modifiers Detected!
>   Keeping the modifiers will increase polycount when returning to edit mode.

[image: warning message]

Also if you hover over the modifier you will see this error message.

> Not supported in dyntopo

[image: error message]

You have to [apply](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17737/2217) the modifier before using dynamic topology.

---

The only way to "rescue" your sculpt now is to go back to a previous save, before you enabled dynamic topology.