# How to make an animation play in the blender game engine?

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

Ok so I have created a character and rigged it and when I hit the play button for the animation it plays just fine.
I have set up the logic bricks multiple time yet whenever I hit <kbd>P</kbd> to play the animation never plays.  I cant seem to find my mistake if anyone could help me it would be much appreciated.

edit: here's the link  [image]

Answer (score 1):

First you had the logic bricks on the wrong object. You needed the Action actuator on the Armature not the mesh object, because it is the armature that is animated.

Your second problem was the mirror modifier (I [applied](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17737/2217) it). The mirror modifier was causing the animation to not play in the BGE. Just another one of the differences between the game engine and blender.
In general you should not have any modifiers or transforms (scale or rotation) on your objects in the BGE.

Your working **[blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/394/)**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i was so puzzled by this but i am very new to the bge so i guess this is something that is learned along the way, thank you for taking the time to look at it and solve my problem:)