# How to apply a modifier in V2.9+

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

Why I can't apply mirror modifier?

Here's screen

[image]

Comment: In addition to susu's answer,
I would add that there is a built-in addon by default.
Modifiers Tools, it adds a button to quickly apply all the changes in one click, also disable visibility in viewport or render.

This is handy because it avoids a lot of popup menu click actions and all the other stuff that makes the software as boring as 3ds.

Comment: This UI solution indeed makes addons for modifiers like Modifiers Tools or Modifiers List even more useful than before since default UI gets less and less convinient and logical in such simple things.

Answer (score 51):

Click on the top triangle to apply the modifier, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Remember, you need to be in **Object Mode** to apply modifiers.

[image]

Comment: The developers, in their infinite wisdom, ah ah

Comment: @moonboots same as [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8)

Comment: I completely agree, same as enable nodes in the Shader Editor, etc... but we get used to it

Comment: @moonboots we get used to it, but how are new users going to guess?

Comment: I don't know, Blender is very disturbing at the beginning for sure, I love it hough, and I think it's getting better, but there are still things that I don't understand... I would say the main improvement would be to create a right click on an object that would allow to have access to a pop up with all its features: modifiers, material, datas, etc, instead of going into the right panel... I still don't understand why it's not implemented yet, or they have try and it was a bad idea?

Comment: also why do we have a separation between dopesheet and timeline, I'm sure it could be merged, or am I missing something? etc etc etc... I guess there is a lot to and I guess it also depends on the amount of employees they have