# How could edit edges made by boolean effect?

Tags: modifiers

In [this video at 16 min. 50 seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM&t=0s) which was made for earlier and he uses boolean effect to carve out a cylinder out of a anvil.

Because of that, there are faces with more than 4 vertices. He uses various methods to reduced faces with more than 4 vertices to 4 vertices.

The problem is that I cannot do what he suggests in the video. I cannot reduce those face because those faces are created by boolean effect, and I cannot do anything with those edges. They cannot be selected.

Do you know any solution for that? In the video, he can edit them but I cannot.

Because you choose "apply" with boolean effect, and that makes carving out effect real but there is no apply button in the latest version of Blender.

Comment: So the question is how to apply modifiers in the latest Blender version...? I guess a Google search with the words "blender apply modifiers" where the first result leads to an answer here in BSE would have been much quicker than typing the new question ;-)

Comment: This was fast too... and one cannot use Google all the time that makes one reduced.

Comment: See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193188/31447

Comment: @Aftershock But at least here's a result already. Users on BSE are advised to look for existing answers before creating duplicates.

Comment: That did not appear on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He applies the boolean operator.  In object mode, select the anvil and go to the modifiers tab.  Click the drop down arrow and select apply.  Now you can edit the mesh.

Comment: Or move the mouse over the  boolean modifier on the modifiers tab so that it's outlined in blue and hit CTRL-A.