# My Blender Model splits in half when imported to spark ar

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image]

Hellooo!Im new to blender and trying to make a filter.... (earrings) every time I import my Evee object to Spark ar it splits in half. I reduced the verticals already and don't know what the problem could be... help would be so appreciated.. All the best, Lara

Comment: do you have any modifiers that perhaps need to be applied? It's hard to figure out without seeing the panels or the actual mesh in Blender

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem is, that I build the model with the mirror modifier? I still haven't solved it tough...

Answer (score 0):

If you used any modifiers in your model you might need to apply it before importing into another application.

As [stated in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193188/20102), in Object Mode use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or go to the Modifiers panel, click on the top triangle and select **Apply**.