# How to switch on the black dots on the edges of the shape to move it around and change the shape?

Tags: edges

[image]

I am making a stickman figure from scratch on a youtube tutorial, but as it seems my blender doesn't have the black dots on the edges of the shape to move it around and change the shape wondering if anyone knew how to switch it on?

Comment: From your image you appear to have a single vert with a ParticleSystem, Skin and Subdivision modifiers on it. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Upload your file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ with a link to it in your question and someone might be able to help, but as it is we're completely in the dark!

Comment: I am making a stickman figure from scratch on a youtube tutorial, but as it seems my blender doesn't have the black dots on the edges of the shape to move it around and change the shape, do you know what I mean?

Comment: Modifiers are procedural effects, and their changes aren't realized until the modifiers are applied.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193188/110840

Comment: I'd suugest you go through Joey Carlino's initial [skin modifier tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAAwy_l4jw4&list=RDCMUCPYtQkET_jYxFvXe34YI3_w) which will teach you how to model figures from scratch using the skin modifier.