# Sub surf modifier not adding more vertices/not showing any more vertices

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm following along blender burus donut tutorial and it seems when I subdivide, it just makes it visually smoother instead of adding more vertices.

Comment: Hi :). It does add more vertices, just won't show them. Uncheck *Optimal Display* in the modifier

Comment: it doesn't add real vertices unless you apply it, they are just virtual vertices for the moment

Comment: i unchecked it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: how do you apply the vertices?

Comment: @PixlBTW https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193188/110840

Comment: That's the whole point of using a modifier! Working with a lot of vertices can be frustrating and in some cases impossible. Modifiers give you the ability to use the benefits vertices bring, without facing their problems!

Comment: THX i felt so relieved :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.