# Does mirror modifier actually create a mesh or is it just a visual effect?

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing, mirror-modifier

I only made half the model and used mirror modifier. If I 3D print my blend file will it just print the half I created or both sides?

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193188/110840

Answer (score 2):

Just the visual effect. Before you export your file for printing, apply the mirror; unless you're sending it to a printer that understands Blend files and knows how to deal with mirrors.

Comment: Note that some exporters give you the option to dynamically apply the modifiers on export, so you can still work with unapplied modifiers in your blend file