# How do I apply an array in the latest version of blender?

Tags: modifiers

Im still very new to blender but I’m making an array of blocks and there’s no apply button to apply the array and make all the blocks individual objects. I watched videos and all of them have this button but mine doesn’t.

Comment: In Blender 2.9 the button is hidden in the drop-down menu. Have a look here https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17733/107598 - You also can hover the mouse over the modifier and press Ctrl+A to apply it.